# Save state of Snackbar after changing orientation

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-snackbar

I want to save the state of `Snackbar` after screen rotation. I can't find any default implementation, like `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState(...)` of `LayoutManager`.

The only way that I see is to keep `boolean show***Snackbar` variable and save/restore it. Any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are no easy way to do this if you are using the native library component. You will have to do this manually.

1. Create a Parcelable model to represent the Snackbar instance.
2. `OnPause()` create the Parcelable and save in the bundle.
3. `OnResume()` recreate the Snackbar using the details in the bundle.